# Create a new column containing the longest string, of days, from another column on the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Number_sensor': [0, 1, 1, 2, 3], 
                         'Time_backup_freq': ['2DAY/36 DAY/12DAY', '12DAY/36 DAY', '12DAY/36DAY', 
                                              '2 DAY', '2 DAY/24 DAY']})

print(df)
```

I would like to create a new column containing the largest number of days that the sensor backs up. I would like the resulting dataframe to be:

```
          Number_sensor    Time_backup_freq          NEW_COLUMNS
             0          2DAY/36 DAY/12DAY               36DAY
             1           12DAY/36 DAY                   36DAY        
             1              12DAY/36DAY                 36DAY
             2                2 DAY                     2DAY
             3             2 DAY/24 DAY                 24DAY


df['Time_backup_freq'] = df['Time_backup_freq'].astype(str)
```

The only thing I could think of is to create an array from the largest to the smallest, like this:

```
array_crescent = np.array(['36 DAY', '36DAY', '24 DAY', '12 DAY', '2 DAY', '2DAY'])
```

But I don't know how to iterate on the dataframe by comparing the larger day string.

I have a new dataframe, this time, not only is Month also an Hour. You would have to adapt the code for this problem (since now 100 HOUR <12DAY)

```
      import pandas as pd

      df = pd.DataFrame({'Number_sensor': [0, 1, 1, 2, 3], 
                         'Time_backup_freq': ['2MO/36 MO/12MO',
                                              '12MO - 36HOUR', 
                                              '12MO/36MO', 
                                              '2 MO/10 HOUR', 
                                              '100 HOUR 24 MO']})
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.extractall` to extract all the numbers, then using `GroupBy.max` to get the `max` per row:

```
df['NEW_COLUMNS'] = (
    df['Time_backup_freq'].str.extractall('(\d+)').groupby(level=0).max().add('DAY')
)


   Number_sensor   Time_backup_freq NEW_COLUMNS
0              0  2DAY/36 DAY/12DAY       36DAY
1              1       12DAY/36 DAY       36DAY
2              1        12DAY/36DAY       36DAY
3              2              2 DAY        2DAY
4              3       2 DAY/24 DAY       24DAY
```

Comment: I ended up discovering that the sensors are also backapped in Hours. That way, would you have how to adjust the script? tks

Answer (score 0):

Considering your numbers are always separated by `/`, and have the example format (you basically can order each frequency alphabetically), you can obtain the largest number like this:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Number_sensor': [0, 1, 1, 2, 3],
...                  'Time_backup_freq': ['2DAY/36 DAY/12DAY', '12DAY/36 DAY', '12DAY/36 DAY',
...                                       '2 DAY', '2 DAY/24 DAY']})
>>> df.Time_backup_freq.str.split('/').apply(max)
0    36 DAY
1    36 DAY
2    36 DAY
3     2 DAY
4    24 DAY
Name: Time_backup_freq, dtype: object
```

Comment: this is risky, you are taking the max on strings.